# Parse.com - update data at a specific time

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I have developed an android application which uses [Parse](http://parse.com) as a back-end database. I use Parse to store `Activity` objects, which are events that are at a specific time and place. I want to be able to mark the `Activity` as "completed" immediately after the activity ends. I have a column that's a boolean named `completed` that's initialized as `false`. When the event ends, immediately I want the `completed` column to change to `true`. The problem is that my android app won't always be open at that specific time, so can't deploy the code there. Any ideas how to do this automatically? Should I use a background cloud code job for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not the downvoter, but this seems less of an android problem and more of a system issue. do you really need to be storing activities to achieve what you need to achieve? could you not just have the android app do the online deployment later? e.g if the app wasn't on and an activity has gone past its time, it could just check them and mark them as not completed or whatever. it's hard to know exactly because it's quite a vague description of what your requirements are and is probably why the downvote occured.. but here you go, back to 0

Comment: The way that the application works is that there are volunteers that sign up for an activity. So i have to update how many hours each volunteer has completed at the end of every activity. There's a reports feature in my app that queries the volunteers based on how many hours they have completed, so I want the most up-to-date data for that.

Comment: right, so an activity isn't actual an android Activity, it's a class you've made called activity or am I mistaken?

Comment: Activity is a class on Parse.com. The class manages all of the activities, and there's also a Volunteer class that represents each volunteer in the application. A volunteer normally signs up for an Activity, and then their "hoursCompleted" field needs to be updated when the Activity is done.

Comment: Right, so to do this, you might not need to be setting these activities as 'completed' and remove etc. Could you not just give them a time and date cut off and on the users end, only show activities that are in range of the users device time & date. Then you don't need this back end thing that is constantly polling to try and remove old activities.

Comment: That may not work because I need to count how many hours each volunteer completes, and I hoping to create some kind of background job that goes through each activity, checks if it's done, and updates the "hoursCompleted" of the volunteers who went. Problem is I need to run this job immediately after an Activity is completed meaning when the cuurent date and time is after the end time of the Activity. Also I'm not trying to remove old activities, I just want to update the Volunteer objects accordingly when each activity is done.

Comment: I don't think you don't need the background job, how about when the volunteer completes, it adds it to the Activity on parse.com with a key & pair value of volunteerID and hoursworked. Then when you want to actually go and look at these Activities, that's when you compile all this information. It doesn't have to happen before you view it as far as I can tell

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: To check when the volunteer completes the activity, I'll probably do that by checking the current time and seeing if the Activity is done or not. I have update the fields immediately after the Activity is done. The problem is when I have to this, it's dynamic based on each Activity, cause each Activity has a different ending date and time. Like I said, I want all of the data to be as up-to-date as possible,so doing things "later" isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to create a date cut off for Activities

2) Now, volunteers are only presented with not completed jobs & dates before the cut off

3) Volunteers log their hours, it updates the Activity with a volunteer ID & the amount of hours they have worked in an array. ***Don't*** store the hours worked on the volunteers ID. You should just take a volunteer ID, iterate through every Activity with that volunteer ID, check if the activity is completed, and if it is, add that users hours to your loop and that total is the amount of hours said volunteer has worked.

so, just make a table called volunteerHrsToJob  and it just contains

```
ID | volunteerID | hoursWorked
```

then you can add a new value to this table, then link the ID's to your activity

Comment: I originally thought about doing what you explained in 3). It may take a long time because if there are a lot of activities looping would take a while,  which is why I was averse to the idea. If you have another idea I'm open to it.

Comment: well, queries processing happen on the server side, so you could use that instead of looping through the activities, e.g query * activities that are completed and have the volunteer ID working in them. or you could add "ActivityID" and "isCompleted" to volunteerHrsToJob table, and add it to both the activity and the volunteersID. it creates a bit of redundancy but in the real world it really doesn't matter

Comment: Actually I figured out a nice way to log hours for the volunteers and fetch them that uses your implementation. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Brilliant, happy coding :D